# How to assemble segments of MQ messages in Spring integration

Tags: spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms, mq

How to handle/assemble segments of a MQ message when using Spring Integration JMS Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter. ? I did find some reference on how to do in when using MQ API .

https://medium.com/@marcus_j/consuming-segmented-ibm-mq-messages-in-java-cbdee4a9ad85

```
MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
gmo.options = MQC.MQGMO_ALL_SEGMENTS_AVAILABLE 
    | MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT 
    | MQC.MQGMO_COMPLETE_MSG;  
gmo.matchOptions = MQC.MQMO_NONE;  
gmo.waitInterval = 10000;
MQMessage message = new MQMessage();   
queue.get(message, gmo);
// Do your stuff with the message
message.clearMessage();
queue.close(); 
manager.disconnect();
```

Per my understanding i will have to pass the appropriate MQGetMessageOptions , to be able to ask the queue manager to reassemble the message if it has been segmented. Could not find any reference on how to pass these options when using spring JMS .

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately IBM MQ does not support [Message segmentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q026370_.html) in JMS:

> This feature is not supported on IBM® MQ for z/OS® or by applications using **IBM MQ classes for JMS**.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Integration doesn't provide channel adapter implementation for IBM MQ API.
On one hand there is a JMS bridge API over IBM MQ: https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/tutorials/mq-develop-mq-jms/

On the other hand (as you already noticed), Spring Integration provides channel adapters for JMS: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jms.html#jms

So, I would try first to use official IBM JMS client and then reach IBM support for de-segmentation option in their JMS client.

There is indeed nothing what Spring Integration can do.

Although you always can write your own `MessageProducerSupport` to perform that IBM MQ-specific logic. You need to implement a `doStart()` and call `sendMessage()` from there when you done an assembling an IBM MQ message and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it is true that you won't be able to use out of the box code to apply the `gmo` options on a `@JmsListener` or a `JmsTemplate`, if you have included the MQ JMS Spring Boot Starter as a dependancy -

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then you do have access to all the MQ Classes that you use in your example. So you can craft your own objects and methods and use them in your Spring application. Although they won't be very JMS Spring like, and the connections won't be managed by Spring.

The difficulty is that `get message options` are applied at the get, and not on the connection. To override options set on the connection you could have created your own customised connection factory bean, but not for `gmo` options.

Comment: chughts, as Daniel Steinmann points out IBM MQ classes for JMS does not support message segmentation as given by the OP in the IBM MQ classes for Java example.   Are you stating there is someway to get this working with JMS?

Comment: No, not with JMS, but using the MQ Classes directly. JMS would be cleaner and more Spring like, but as everyone is stating, they don't support message segmentation.