# How to recover from com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2009'

Tags: spring, spring-integration, ibm-mq, mq

I'm writing a consumer to read segmented messages from MQ . I was using using Spring JMS / Spring Integration for the other queues. I understand IBM MQ does not support Message segmentation in JMS:
( Related question here.
[How to assemble segments of MQ messages in Spring integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66354127/how-to-assemble-segments-of-mq-messages-in-spring-integration) )

Here is the approach i came up with to use IBM MQ classes for java and Spring .

Bean definitions for MQ objects.

```
@Bean
    public MQGetMessageOptions mqGetMessageOptions() {
        MQGetMessageOptions getOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
        getOptions.waitInterval = CMQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED;
        getOptions.options = CMQC.MQGMO_WAIT + CMQC.MQGMO_ALL_SEGMENTS_AVAILABLE + CMQC.MQGMO_LOGICAL_ORDER
                + CMQC.MQGMO_COMPLETE_MSG;
        return getOptions;
    }

    @Bean
    public MQQueueManager mqQueueManager() throws Exception {
        Hashtable<String, Object> properties = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        properties.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel);
        properties.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
        properties.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, new Integer(port));
        MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(queueManager, properties);
        return qMgr;
    }

    @Bean
    public MQQueue inboundQueue(@Autowired MQQueueManager mqQueueManager) throws Exception {
        int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_EXCLUSIVE;
        MQQueue inboundQueue = mqQueueManager.accessQueue(inboundQueue, openOptions);
        return inboundQueue;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel queueConsumerChannel() {
        // return new DirectChannel();
        return new ExecutorChannel(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5));
    }
```

Consumer code :

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MyQueueConsumer {

    @Autowired
    MQQueueManager qMgr;

    @Autowired
    MQGetMessageOptions mqGetMessageOptions;

    @Autowired
    MQQueue inboundQueue;

    @Autowired
    MessageChannel queueConsumerChannel;

    @Autowired
    MessageSaveService messageSaveService;


    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void consume() {
        boolean getMore = true;
        MQMessage receiveMsg = null;
        while (getMore) {
            try {
                receiveMsg = new MQMessage();
                log.info("Waiting to consume mesages from ....");
                inboundQueue.get(receiveMsg, mqGetMessageOptions);
                byte[] b = new byte[receiveMsg.getMessageLength()];
                receiveMsg.readFully(b);
                String fileName = getFileName();
                Message<String> outMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(new String(b)).build();
                queueConsumerChannel.send(outMessage);
                log.info("Message consumed and sent to processng channel");
                // qMgr.commit();
            } catch (MQException e) {
                if ((e.completionCode == CMQC.MQCC_WARNING) && (e.reasonCode == CMQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE)) {
                    log.error("Bottom of the queue reached.");

                    getMore = false;
                } else {
                    log.error("MQRead CC=" + e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode + " : EC=" + e.getErrorCode());
                    log.info("Is Connected :" + qMgr.isConnected());
                    log.info("Is open : " + qMgr.isOpen());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    getMore = false;
                }
            } 
        }

    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void closeMQObjects() {
        System.out.println("Closing MQ objects ");
        try {
            if (inboundQueue != null)
                inboundQueue.close();
        } catch (MQException e) {
            System.err.println("MQRead CC=" + e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (qMgr != null)
                qMgr.disconnect();
        } catch (MQException e) {
            System.err.println("MQRead CC=" + e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

With this configuration Consumer works as desired , it assembles all the segmented messages and reads as one complete message and waits on the queue for the next message to arrive.
But the challenge i'm facing is i see

`com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2009'`

every once in a while . I'm making the flag false to come out of the while loop.
So far could not figure out the exact reason for this exception .
How do i recover from this exception and continue to wait on the queue and consume messages when they arrive?
Are there any flaws in the approach i have taken using spring and IBM MQ

Comment: Please, see here: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/resolving-jmsexception-due-comibmmqmqexception-mqje001-completion-code-2-reason-2009. Doesn't look like the problem is related to Spring some how at all...

Comment: I agree.. It's not related to Spring .

Comment: What is your SVRCONN HBINT set to?   You can find this with a IBM MQ classes for Java trace if you do not know.   Did your connection pass through and network devices that do time the connection out such as a firewall or load balancer?

Comment: The comments on this question provide the trace details and what to look for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64284625/ibm-mq-session-disconnects

Comment: SVRCONN HBINT is set to default HBINT(300) .                                                       Not sure if this can be set on the client code .I don't have a value set on the client side. I was able to connect and read messages. I see this exception after a while waiting on the queue to receive message

Comment: Try having the SVRCONN HBINT set much lower like 15 or 20.

Comment: @JoshMc Thanks . Its been a over a day and i did not see the exception after setting SVRCONN HBINT to 20.On a different note, Is it a good practice to catch   2009 and try to reconnect ? What is the significance of  MQCNO_RECONNECT in case of any broken connection exception?

Comment: IBM MQ classes for Java does not support auto reconnect, `MQCNO_RECONNECT` should have no impact.  It is s best practice to catch 2009 and reconnect and reopen your queues.

Comment: Does your MQ network connection pass through any network devices that could time the connection out such as a firewall or load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining `inboundQueue` as a bean, allocate it in the while loop and `close` it when you successfully end the loop or encounter a retryable exception.

Unfortunately I can not give you a list of retryable exception, but `2009` is definitely one of them.

It is is good practice to delay the retries, see for example [ExponentialBackOff](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/backoff/ExponentialBackOff.html).